# Analytics Solution for new SAAS application

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a new tech startup creating interactive videos and i need to implement an analytics layer.  This layer needs to track time on video, if a user clicks on interactions, etc etc.  Can someone suggest if there is a 3rd party analytics solution I could use to implement this?  I am not sure if I can use google analytics to capture the data and then display a custom dashboard on the data it collects?  Another alternative is should i try to roll my own solution (i have never done this).

Any advice on a possible solution / route would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analytics for this, it support custom defined events and you can trigger it whenever event you want to track happens.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

There are many other SAAS platforms, which you can check. Even some Front-End only libraries with defined API so you can create your own infrastructure.

- https://matomo.org/
- https://count.ly/web-analytics
- https://mixpanel.com/

Comment: Thanks for this.. Does google provide an API for me to query this data back into my system and provide a front end for it?  So i could tag each event with a customer / project name and then display them accordingly

Comment: There are lot of API provided by Google Analytics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4 . It also support to retrive these Events data. Probably it won't cover all possible use cases you may have in future, but it is simple enough to start with.

Comment: >>  So i could tag each event with a customer : No, Google Analytics doesn't work that way, it's designed to report aggregated data on user behaviour.

Comment: ah...so not sure on the best way to segregate data on a customer / project basis..